# Does pandas df.to_sql() rollback?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am using pandas to write data to an SQL database via SQLalchemy.

I am loading data to a DataFrame and then using the to_sql() method.

Does the pandas to_sql() method rollback?
As in, if an error occurs during the insertion of the data to the database, can I roll it back to the original?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the context manager, rollback is taken care of automatically if there's an error:

```
with engine.begin() as conn:
    df1.to_sql(con=conn, ...)
    df2.to_sql(con=conn, ...)
```

For more information, read this: [to_sql rollback](https://capelastegui.wordpress.com/2018/05/21/commit-and-rollback-with-pandas-dataframe-to_sql/)

Comment: Ok, thanks. What's the difference between ```engine.begin()``` and ```engine.connect()```? Will the above work with ```engine.connect()```?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that, apart from the accepted answer, you can make use of the same connection (`conn` instance) for any SQL you want:

```
with engine.begin() as conn:
    df1.to_sql(con=conn, ...)
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO...")
    df2.to_sql(con=conn, ...)
    conn.execute("UPDATE FROM...")
    conn.execute("DELETE FROM...")
```

If there are any uncatched exception inside the `with` block, Pandas will  `ROLLBACK` all the operations. Otherwise, Pandas will `COMMIT` all of them.

Comment: RemovedIn20Warning: Passing a string to Connection.execute() is deprecated and will be removed in version 2.0.  Use the text() construct, or the Connection.exec_driver_sql() method to invoke a driver-level SQL string. (Background on SQLAlchemy 2.0 at: https://sqlalche.me/e/b8d9)

Answer (score -1):

Rollback and continuing example

```
connection = engine.connect()
for i in range(0,x):  
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)  
    transaction = connection.begin()   
    try:  
        df.to_sql("db_name", engine, if_exists='append')  
        transaction.commit()  
    except:  
        transaction.rollback()
        print(str(i) + ' - rolledback')
```